# Multiply with Previous Value from One colum in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I have the following result, which is easily calculated in Excel, but how to do it in Oracle, the result is the following, based on a previous select and comes from one column,

```
  Result from select   Expected result
  1.62590                 
  0.60989                0.991620151 
  0.83859                0.831562742
```

the result is based on    1.62590 * 0.60989   = 0.991620151,
1.62590  * 0.60989  *   0.83859    = 0.831562742

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       result,
       EXP(SUM(LN(result)) OVER (ORDER BY id)) AS expected
FROM   table_name;
```

*Note: Use any other column instead of `id` to give the appropriate ordering or, if your rows are already ordered, use the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column instad of `id`.*

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, Result) AS
SELECT 1, 1.62590 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0.60989 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 0.83859 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | RESULT | EXPECTED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.6259 | 1.62590000000000000000000000000000000001 |
| 2 | .60989 | .9916201510000000000000000000000000000026 |
| 3 | .83859 | .8315627424270900000000000000000000000085 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/neRJjzW8)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a recursive CTE; it, though, expects that sample data can be sorted, somehow, so I added the ID column which starts with 1, while other values are incremented by 1:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  test (id, col) as
  3    (select 1, 1.62590 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 0.60989 from dual union all
  5     select 3, 0.83859 from dual
  6    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  7  product (id, col, prod) as
  8    (select id, col, col
  9     from test
 10     where id = 1
 11     union all
 12     select t.id, t.col, t.col * p.prod
 13     from test t join product p on p.id + 1 = t.id
 14    )
 15  select id,
 16         round(prod, 10) result
 17  from product;

        ID     RESULT
---------- ----------
         1     1,6259
         2 ,991620151
         3 ,831562742

SQL>
```

Comment: if i have id  but it's always the same,will this concept work

Comment: If it is the same, then there's no use of it (because of `p.id + 1 = t.id`). Have a look at answer MT0 posted, it requires *any* kind of sorting (i.e. values don't have to be consecutive).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MODEL` clause:

```
SELECT *  
FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn, result FROM table_name)
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES ( result, 0 AS expected)
  RULES (
    expected[rn] = result[cv()] * COALESCE(expected[cv()-1], 1)
)
order by rn;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, Result) AS
SELECT 1, 1.62590 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0.60989 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 0.83859 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| RN | RESULT | EXPECTED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.6259 | 1.6259 |
| 2 | .60989 | .991620151 |
| 3 | .83859 | .83156274242709 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bxB24sJL)